# How to check when element moves from one class to another

Tags: java, selenium, user-interface, testing, automated-tests

Im have trouble figuring out an issue. Im testing a betting website. Within this website there are different games. When a user logs into the site and there is a game the havent joined its an "Available Game". When the user joins this game its an "Active Game" and when its over its in the "Game History". Each of these states have a different class:
Available = card_7m62gg
Active = card_5pbdh7,
History = card_5pbdh8

So when a user joins a game with an id `5b3a0ac14887fb004a847462` the game moves from `card_7m62gg` to `card_5pbdh7`. How could i test that this movement is occurring. Ive attached a screenshot of the html.

[image]

Comment: What is the code that you tried? Should be simple enough. You change game from one state to another by clicking (or which ever way it should be) and then assert for the element to be present under another div using that xpath or some other locator property.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Yup im just trying to assert the href is in the class but the href seems above the class and i dont know how to check is the class within the href or the other way around??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the above screen shot, your above stated condition is for available & Active state not true. Even when the class "`Active = card_5pbdh7`" is appearing under the link/href, the original href is still under the div - class "`Available = card_7m62gg`" when in active state as shown in the second set of red boxes in the screen shot. But the `<section class="card_gwlf0h">` is changing to `<section class="card_5pbdh7">`. If this is true then you can assert this change to confirm the movement. Assert the following element found by CSS selector

`"a[href*= '5b3a0ac14887fb004a847462'] > .card_gwlf0h"` before the games moves to active state.

`"a[href*= '5b3a0ac14887fb004a847462'] > .card_5pbdh7"` after the games moves to active state.

You can even parameterise the gameid , something like:

```
"a[href*= '" + gameId + "'] > .card_gwlf0h"
```

Comment: 5b3a0ac14887fb004a847462 , this is random string , you should not use this to give answers to user. Nobody knows when it is going to change.

Comment: Thanks for the help, should i find this as an xpath and assert its true? I cant seem to save it as the gameid changes so i cant save it as an element

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment "trying to assert the href is in the class but the href seems above the class" , you can write **xpath** as :

```
//h3[contains(text(),'Active Games')]/following-sibling::div/descendant::a
```

In code :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(text(),'Active Games')]/following-sibling::div/descendant::a")).click();
```

Or you assert also as per your requirement.